# Incorrect Syntax Near `=` - SQL Expression

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to include a conditional check in a `WHERE` statement.But i keep getting Invalid expression at `= 3`

```
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND CLM.myval = 3
          AND 
          CASE APEL.numval
          WHEN 1 THEN  CLM.value =  3 END
```

Basically i want to check CLM.VALUE=3 when APEL.numval=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean logical implication `APEL.numval=1 -> CLM.VALUE=3` then

```
..
AND (APEL.numval <> 1 OR CLM.VALUE = 3)
```

Comment: I want to check CLM.VALUE=3 when APEL.numval=1 otherwise this AND Condition should not be executed.Does your code address this issue.

Comment: @techno , when APEL.numval <> 1  the condition is true whatever CLM.VALUE is. Yes.

Comment: Just to clarify - Basically i want to check CLM.VALUE=3 when APEL.numval=1 otherwise this AND Condition should not be executed. ie: the check should not be done

Comment: @techno, Sql is declarative language, so the order of expressions evaluation within their definitions is up to the optimizer.  The result is exactly as you required.  You can esily check  outcome of all 4 possible combinations.

Comment: say when APEL.numval is 5 ,then the AND expression wont be executed i guess

Answer (score 1):

`CASE WHEN` expression returns **null** if the condition is not met(unless specified with `ELSE`) so in your case when the condition is not met the query could become:

```
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND CLM.myval = 3
          AND NULL --when condition not net
```

which would result in a syntax error, thus you cannot use the whole comparison within the `CASE WHEN` statement. You can return a column or hard-coded data.

I would consider logical bypasses or other library/framework that supports dynamic query handling or use pl/sql to handle if/else cases.

It's not ideal, but if the **3** you are comparing to in `CLM.value = 3` is constant, your query could be changed to:

```
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND CLM.myval = 3
          AND (CASE APEL.numval
               WHEN 1 THEN CLM.value
                      ELSE 3
               END) = 3
```

which would result in following:

1. when condition is met: compares `CLM.VALUE = 3`
2. when condition is not met: compares `3 = 3` (meaningless true statement)

Comment: Have you seen answer by @Serg. What do you think about it?

Comment: While your answer is almost correct (The code does what it should, but the reason for the error in the question is that case can't be used as a flow control element but only as an expression), Serg's answer encapsulate the same logic in less code, without loosing readability - so IMHO, his code is better.

Comment: I've just seen it and I agree it's far simpler and does the job! and thanks @ZoharPeled for your clarification!

Comment: I have upvoted your answer for the explanation.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not have the CASE expression like that.

It should be like

```
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
      AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
      AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
      AND CLM.myval = 3
      AND clm.value =
      CASE APEL.numval
      WHEN 1 THEN 3 END
```

Comment: Thanks.will the `clm.value` check executed only when apel.numval=1

Comment: and when APEL.numval is any value other than 1 nothing will be returned from the quest because the case expression will return null, and `x = null` always return false (well, unknown actually but it's equivalent to false in this case), even if `x` is null...